# Regex to match html tags excluding some

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I want remove all html opening/closing tags (including attributes) that are not present in my list

```js
const allowedTags = ['a', 'b', 'i', 's', 'u', 'sup', 'sub', 'strong', 'cite', 'code', 'del', 'em'];
```

#### Example

input

```html
<b><i><img src="http://example.com"/>Test<strong>Passed</strong><span>without any errors</span><a href="http://example.com">click here</a></b></i>
```

output

```html
<b><i>Test<strong>Passed</strong>without any errors<a href="http://example.com">click here</a></b></i>
```

I tried this

```js
let regex = new RegExp(`<\/?(?!${allowedTags.join('|')})[^>]*>`, 'g')
str.replace(regex, '')
```

What I wanted to achieve

- `<` starts with `<`
- `\/?` may or not contain the `/`
- `(?!${allowedTags.join('|')})` none of those tags *(new to Negative Lookahead)*
- `[^>]*` anything not a `>` (to get the attributes)
- `>` ends with `>`

Comment: If your HTML tags could be nested like this, then regex alone won't do, and you'll need a parser (side note: JavaScript is already a DOM parser).

Comment: I just want to remove the tags, leaving the text-content. So nested tags don't really matter

Comment: I think it would be far safer to **look for a good JavaScript HTML sanitizer**: https://www.google.com/search?q=best+javascript+html+sanitizer I'm sure that Wysiwyg editors such as CKEditor or Tiny MCE already use a library for that purpose.

Comment: Typically, `<strong onmouseover="alert('Shit happens...')">Pass over me with your mouse</strong>` is allowed. But would you like to see the disaster if the user could input this allowed tag?

Comment: I'm trying to "sanitize more" some html retrieved from a Spring backend, which was originaly created with CK-Editor (else-where), I want to remove images, tables, lists... as you guys mentionned, a sanitizer looks like the best solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments before, don't try to do that with a regular expression. You'll lead to problems and severe security holes.

Seems that [sanitize-html](https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html) or [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) will be the best option for your case.

If your backend is running on another techno, such as *PHP*, then don't forget that you should also sanitize server-side with a lib like [Symfony's HTML sanitizer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/html_sanitizer.html), as spoofing an HTTP Post request is very easy to do.

The *JavaScript* sanitizing on the front side should also be done to protect the user from a copy-paste of evil HTML.